# Trying to "redirect_to :back" after logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, redirecttoaction

I'm trying to redirect to the previous page after a user logs in. I am using a bootstrap modal for login/register forms but if someone doesn't have JS enabled on their browser and are taken to the '/login' page, I want to make sure they are redirected to the root url. I know current_page? does not work with POST requests.

I've tried tons of things so the following code is redirecting correctly from the '/login' page to the root url but I am not being redirected to ':back' when logging in using the bootstrap modal.

This is from SessionsController: (PS- I have sessions#new/sessions#create as /login in routes)

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]) 
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id

            if request.path === '/login'
                redirect_to '/'
            else
                redirect_to :back
            end

            flash[:success] = "Logged in."

    else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Email and password did not match. Please try again."
        render :new
    end
end

def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:success] = "Logged out."
    redirect_to '/'
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root to: 'home#home'

resources :users

get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

Comment: why dont you have the redirect to `root_path`. I think that should work

Comment: @Mukul215 anytime I use "root_path" I get an error saying: "**undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<SessionsController:0x007fdddf451928>**". And my code is redirecting to the root url just fine, it's just not redirecting to ":back" when using the bootstrap-modal.

Comment: in your `routes.rb` file have a defined `root_path` example: `root to: 'controller#action'` or where ever you want to root to.

Comment: @mukul215 Cool well that fixes my root_path issue. But my modal form is still redirecting to the root page instead of to the previous page.

Comment: have you created sessions?

Comment: @Mukul215 I saw that but I thought that was just if you were using the devise gem for a login form

Comment: can you posts your `routes.rb` @BB123

Comment: @Mukul215 updated original post with routes.rb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out.

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root to: 'home#home'

resources :users

get '/login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

SessionsController.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]) 
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id

            if request.referrer == login_url
                redirect_to root_path
            else
                redirect_to :back
            end

            flash[:success] = "Logged in."

    else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Email and password did not match. Please try again."
        render :new
    end
end

def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:success] = "Logged out."
    redirect_to root_path
end

end
```

So if the user logs in using the Bootstrap Modal while on any other page than the `login_url`, they will be redirected back to the current page they were on. If they log in from the actual login page then they will be redirected to `root_path`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works:

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root to: 'home#home'

resources :users

get  '/login',  to: 'sessions#new',    as: 'login' 
post '/login',  to: 'sessions#create'
get  '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

Controller.rb

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]) 
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id

            if request.path === '/login'
                redirect_to '/'
            else
                redirect_to login_url
                flash[:notice] = "Incorrect information"
            end

            flash[:success] = "Logged in."

    else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Email and password did not match. Please try again."
        render :new
    end
end

def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:success] = "Logged out."
    redirect_to '/'
end
```

I created something like a while back. Check this out, it might help you later.
https://github.com/Mukul215/micropost_app/blob/master/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb